# No actualizar ciertos campos mientras estén vacíos en MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente función

```
    $sql = 'UPDATE Tabla SET
                        Campo1 = ".$campo1.",
                        Campo2 = ".$campo2.",
                        Campo3 = ".$campo3."
                        WHERE Id = '.$Id;

$resultado = mysql_query($sql, $this->Conexion) or die ("Error: $sql. ".mysql_error());
```

¿Existe alguna forma de solo actualizar un campo? si solo paso un valor a "$Campo2", los demás se actualizan en "".

Comment: Debes construir tu query dependiendo de si esas variables tienen o no información

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, la mejor solo incuir en el SET los campos que quieras. Otra opcion es un trigger en inserción

Comment: Una opción (que no se si sea la correcta) es que se "actualicen" todos, a que me refiero, pues por ejemplo: Tienes una tabla y haces click en una de sus celdas para editar ese registro, los campos de la fila seleccionada se vacían en un form, actualizas lo que desees y ya los mandas al php que actualiza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes construir en `php` la query en función de lo que tiene valor, por ejemplo:

```
$update = ""; $first_upd = 1;
if ($campo1 != "") { 
  if ($first_upd == 0) { $update .= " , "; }
  $update .= " Campo1 = '".$campo1."' ";  
  $first_upd = 0;
}
if ($campo2 != "") { 
  if ($first_upd == 0) { $update .= " , "; }
  $update .= " Campo2 = '".$campo2."' ";  
  $first_upd = 0;
}
if ($campo3 != "") { 
  if ($first_upd == 0) { $update .= " , "; }
  $update .= " Campo3 = '".$campo3."' ";  
  $first_upd = 0;
}
```

Según como tengas almacenados los campos anteriores, podrías construir $update recorriendo los valores con un bucle en lugar de varios `ifs`.
Y lasnzas la query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE Tabla SET
                        $update
                        WHERE Id = '.$Id;
```

Comment: Buena opción también, además controlas la coma bastante fácilmente.

Comment: Es muy cómoda cuando tienes los datos en un bucle :)

Comment: Si miras mi respuesta, es algo más corta, pero es claramente más díficil de leer, no la voy a borrar, porque siempre está bien tener el máximo de ejemplos, pero me ha gustado más tu método xD

Comment: No, no borres, siempre es mejor tener más opciones y las dos están correctas

Comment: Definitivamente la respuesta de Enrique parece mas compacta, pero si tengo 15 campos tendría que agregarlos en lo que dice "encadenando ternarias" para solucionar el problema de las comas... la respuesta de Carmen me parece mas eficiente, si se pudieran fusionar las 2 seria genial... gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Sí, puedes utilizar operadores ternarios :
**Ejemplo**

```
$valor = (isset($campo)? $campo : "");
```

Esto quiere decir (a partir del igual): si existe `$campo`, `$valor=$campo`, si no `$valor=""` que en `sql` se traduce como nada, ya que es un `string` vacío.

Con eso puedes hacer, por ejemplo:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE Tabla SET";
 $sql .= isset($campo1)? " Campo1 = ".$campo1./*Esto controla la aparición de la coma*/((isset($campo2)||isset($campo3))?", ": "" ): "";
 $sql .= isset($campo2)? " Campo2 = ".$campo2.(isset($campo3)?", ": "" ): "";
 $sql .= isset($campo3)? " Campo3 = ".$campo3 : "";
 $sql .= "WHERE Id = ".$Id;

 $resultado = mysql_query($sql, $this->Conexion) or die ("Error: $sql. ".mysql_error());
```

De esta forma, si no existe el `$campo1`, la query quedará:

```
UPDATE Tabla set Campo2 = valor2, Campo3 = valor3 WHERE Id = id
```

Si no existe `$campo2`:

```
UPDATE Tabla set Campo1 = valor1, Campo3 = valor3 WHERE Id = id
```

ETC

Comment: Si no existe el "campo3" te dara un error a nivel de Base de datos. Por la última comilla que quede.

Comment: @DMAVE Actualizado, encadenando ternarias se arregla eso siempre xD PD: Gracias por la observación, no me habia fijado

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar los valores dependiendo de que parámetro envías. Y los que no envies simplemente colocas el mismo valor para no modificarlo

```
// Solo para el caso en el que NO envíes ningún parámetro a actualizar
if (!empty($campo1) || !empty($campo2) || !empty($campo3)) { 
    $sql = 'UPDATE Tabla SET
                    Campo1 = '.(!empty($campo1) ? "'".$campo1."'" : "Campo1").',
                    Campo2 = '.(!empty($campo2) ? "'".$campo2."'" : "Campo2").',
                    Campo3 = '.(!empty($campo3) ? "'".$campo3."'" : "Campo3").'
                    WHERE Id = '.$Id;

    $resultado = mysql_query($sql, $this->Conexion) or die ("Error: $sql. ".mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Ese método solo creará un problema, si ya tienes relleno el registro que quieres editar y le pasas `Campo1 = Campo1`, se cargará lo que tenga antes y pondrá "Campo1" en ese campo.

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil justamente eso es lo que necesita. NO ACTUALIZAR ese campo, simplemente se actualizaría con el mismo valor que tenia anteriormente en caso de que no se envie.

Comment: El resultado en caso de que se envie solo $campo2 por ejemplo. Update Tabla SET Campo1 = Campo1, Campo2 = '$campo2', Campo3 = Campo3 WHERE Id = $Id

Comment: Pero lo suyo es que si no existe el valor `$campo1`, no introduzca `Campo1` en el sql

Comment: @DMAVE Es correcto lo que dices, pero realmente si estas actualizando el dato, es decir, estas ejecutando una instrucción de hacer update de esos campos justamente con el valor de ese campo, y son cosas que te puedes ahorrar para optimizar procesos, así que lo mejor es construir la query dinamicamente y sólo poner lo que se va a actualizar.

Comment: Seria reemplazar el empty por el isset. En la descripción de la pregunta no indica si las variables no se envían o si estas variables simplemente están vacías.

Comment: @Marc Optimizar la consulta para expandir el proceso en PHP. Todo es cuestión de perspectiva. Tendrías que verificar como lo muestra Carmen en su respuesta. No veo optimo cargar tantas condicionales.

Comment: @DMAVE pero la cosa es que si `$campo1` no existe, o no tiene valor, como vea ya Alf, NO introduzca la parte "Campo1 = loquesea"

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil  La programación siempre es cuestion de perspectiva, yo no sobrecargo el servidor PHP ya que el SQL siempre es mucho mas optimo. Tu respuesta es igual de valida que la mía.

Comment: No he dicho que no lo sea. No quiero meterme contigo ni nada, no te lo tomes a mal, simplemente te damos nuestra opinión, y quién sabe si a lo mejor alguna de ellas te gusta. No hay nada de malo en exponer nuestras dudas respecto a tu respuesta. Repito: no es ningún ataque opinar sobre el código, eso es lo que la mayoría de las veces nos hace mejorar, si no te parece buena idea, no lo cambias, pero si descubres una forma que te propongan y te guste más puede ser bueno

Comment: @enriquemanzanogil entiendo tu punto de vista. Por eso desde un principio dije que optimizar la consulta expande el proceso en PHP. La cantidad de validaciones. Depende de como uses y tengas optimizado cada uno de los servidores/servicios.

Comment: Eso lo comprendo, mi opinión puede ser basada también en que me gusta que el sql sea lo más corto y simple posible, pero es verdad que si tienes el cuidado suficiente y configuras bien la sentencia, no haya fallos. Lo único es eso, que no me gusta la idea de que en algún momento pueda fallar algo y cambiarme un dato que no deba xD